# What's this Japanese food?

Tags: japan, food-and-drink, identify-this, asia

In this Japan travel promotion [video](https://youtu.be/HrBxi37AQms), this fried I think food is displayed, screenshot from the hot pan:

[image]

What is this?

Comment: I think it’s very small fish, actually. You can see the tiny eyes. It’s apparently called shirasu https://www.zojirushi.com/blog/?p=3525 not sure I ever tried that.

Comment: Hmm seems you are right @jcaron, but after reading your link, I am severely scoked as a Greek. Is that **baby fish**? Or it's just that they are really small by nature, and it's okay to consume them in a sustainable of course method.

Comment: I’m pretty sure there is something similar in Greek cuisine. French and Spanish people definitely eat similar fish (a little bit bigger but not much) deep fried, I would be surprised if that didn’t exist in Greek cuisine.

Comment: @jcaron then yes, they are baby fish, is that even legal?! I think it was in Greece, but after mankind overfished the seas, it's not illegal, or at least this is the plan (when I had to leave it was still on forming the papers). Anyway, thanks for answering my question. I now have to report that crime, it's not sustainable.

Comment: How is that a crime? It's just animals that are bred for the purpose of eating them, like nearly all the meat and a lot of the fish you eat. I know some people want to outlaw that, but for now it's all perfectly legal in most countries.

Comment: @jcaron you are talking about aquacultures, but I am talking about the wild baby fish. I mean thinking about whales and Japan is enough to get me very worried about this situation. Anyway, that's off topic though..Sorry!

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is fish that has been bred in captivity. It would be near impossible to fish that in the open sea. Those fish are **tiny**. They're at most 1 mm wide.

Comment: A cod will produce about 40,000,000 baby cod; about 2 survive to breed. It is the fate of most baby fish to die by suffocation, complicated by digestion.

Comment: @jcaron The UK equivalent, whitebait, is certainly fished in the open sea. All you need is a fine net, and knowing how to be in the right place at the right time. People have been eating it in the UK for at least 400 years, and the species haven't gone extinct yet, despite the Marine Conservation Society whining about it being unsustainable.

Comment: I have cleaned up the comment series of the question and the answers. Please keep it too the facts, do not copy information that is already in the answers and keep out politics and personal habits.

Comment: @gsamaras: It might not be a crime but it definitely feels wrong, especially considering that eels are critically endangered. [Elvers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eel_as_food) used to be a cheap dish but are now considered a delicacy and are priced at up to 1000 euro per kilogram. It's just like this [simpsons episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a7mvRdpGRQI).

Comment: @gsamaras atherina isn't the same as gonos. Those look like small atherina to me (but I may well be wrong).

Comment: There are other baby tiny fish eaten in Japan. The ones I know are called chirimenjako but they look more silver compared to these white ones.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's called 'Shirasu'. It's the juvenile offspring of anchovies, herrings or sardines.

In other parts of the world it's called 'whitebait' or 'gianchetti', or...other names. The exact species varies from place to place too.

reference: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitebait)

Comment: @gsamaras It's very legal and very common through East Asia. Those baby fish are raised for specifically this purpose.

Answer (score 10):

It looks like [**shirasu**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitebait#Japan) (or "whitebait"):

[image: Shirasu]